# Save output of Mathematica batch job to file

Tags: output, scripting, save

```
bsub "math -script input.m > output.out"
```

runs the Mathematica command in `input.m` as a batch job and should print the output to file `output.out`. However, nothing is printed into `output.out`.

What am I supposed to do?

Comment: Would it be possible for you to run the contents of the script interactively in a notebook to check the script is actually working and producing output, before trying to run it unattended?

Comment: @MarcoB No. I just want to find a foolproof way to print the output of a Mathematica script.

Comment: I don’t think I was clear. I meant, are you sure that the code in your script actually works and produces an output?

Comment: Have you considered using the `Put` or `Export` inside your script to write the output to disk. This is more robust and less dependent on subtle differences in operating system etc.

Comment: @MarcoB I tried it on my machine after forever: it does print an output.

Comment: @mmeent I will follow your advice, thanks